# Every real function has a dense set on which its restriction is continuous

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, gn.general-topology, real-analysis

The title says it all: if $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is any real function, there exists a dense subset $D$ of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_D$ is continuous.

Or so I'm told, but this leaves me stumped.  Apart from the rather trivial fact that one can find a dense $D$ such that the graph of $f|_D$ has no isolated points (by a variant of Cantor-Bendixson), I don't know how to start.  Is this a well-known fact?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is a theorem due to Blumberg (*New Properties of All Real Functions* - Trans. AMS (1922)) and a topological space $X$ such that every real valued function admits a dense set on which it is continuous is sometimes called a Blumberg space.

Moreover, in Bredford & Goffman, *Metric Spaces in which Blumberg's Theorem Holds*, Proc. AMS (1960) you can find the proof that a metric space is Blumberg iff it's a Baire space.

Comment: Blumberg's paper is online: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1922-024-02/S0002-9947-1922-1501216-9/S0002-9947-1922-1501216-9.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference!  For completeness, there's a self-contained and rather nice proof (or at least nicer than Blumberg's original one) of the statement, plus an extensive discussion, in the more general setting, in chapter 8 of Goffman, Nishiura, and Waterman's book *Homeomorphisms in Analysis*, available online at http://www.ams.org/publications/online-books/surv54-index