# Is a function piecewise continuous if it has a left-limit and a right-limit at every point in its interval domain and equals at least one of these?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Suppose a real-valued function f, whose domain is an interval, has the property that
at every point in its domain it has a left-limit and a right-limit, and it equals at least one of these.  Is it true that

1: f has at most a countable number of discontinuities. (Young's theorem would appear to say "yes".)

2. f can be called piecewise continuous. (Some say "piecewise continuity" requires a finite number of discontinuities.)

Comment: Here's an easy example: enumerate the rationals in $[0,1]$ as $(a_n)$. Then for $t \in [0,1]$ define $f(t) = \sum \{2^{-n}: a_n \leq t\}$. This is an increasing function which is discontinuous at every rational.

Comment: The answer to 2. and 3. is no. In fact it is no even if the two one-sided limits agree. See for instance: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/698448/787383

Comment: On question 1. this can help: https://mathoverflow.net/a/231462/167834

Comment: Are you a student? Here is an exercise for you. Prove that a function on a closed interval has the property you want if and only if it is a uniform limit of a sequence of step functions.

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of Thomae's function or Young's theorem.  Please comment on my current understanding.  If a real-valued function, whose domain is an interval, has left- and right-limits and equals at least one of them at each point in the domain, then it is continuous, except possibly at a countable number of points.

Comment: Addendum: I had intended to add the following to my comment: "And one can say the function is piecewise continuous."

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you know this example.  (Found in the [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379332/is-a-function-piecewise-continuous-if-it-has-a-left-limit-and-a-right-limit-at-e#comment962906_379332) by DellaCorte.) It is likely to be seen in a calculus course ….

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b}, & \text{if $x = \frac{a}{b}$ is rational in lowest terms,} \\
0, & \text{if $x$ is irrational.}
\end{cases}
$$
This function is continuous at every irrational, discontinuous at every rational, and has left and right limit $0$ everywhere.