# Does every real function have this weak continuity property?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In my research I came across the following question :

> Is it true that for every real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a real sequence $(x_n)_n$, taking infinitely many values, converging to some real number $c$, such that the sequence $(f(x_n))_n$  converges to $f(c)$ ?

Comment: The question looks interesting, because $f$ is not assumed to have any property (such as continuity).  Perhaps prove first this.  There is $a$ so that for every $\epsilon > 0$, the set $\{x \; : \; |f(x) - f(a)|<\epsilon \}$ is uncountable.

Comment: The difficulty is to have, $f(x_n)$ converged to $f(a)$ and $x_n$ converged to $a$.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : for your question, you can show that with compacity argument

Comment: I had to read it like four times before I convinced myself that this is not an immediately false triviality.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Suppose $f$ were a counterexample. Then, for any $c$, we could find a little interval $(a,b)$ containing $c$ and we could find some $\varepsilon>0$ such that all points $x\in(a,b)$ except $c$ have $|f(x)-f(c)|>\varepsilon$. (Otherwise, by taking smaller and smaller intervals and $\varepsilon$'s, we could produce a sequence converging to $c$ with $f$-image converging to $f(c)$.) By shrinking things a little, we can arrange for $a$, $b$, and $\varepsilon$ to always be rational. So uncountably many $c$'s must have the same $a$, $b$, and $\varepsilon$. Fix such $a$, $b$, and $\varepsilon$. So you've got uncountably many $c$'s, all lying in $(a,b)$ and (therefore) all having their $f(c)$'s separated by a distance of at least $\varepsilon$ --- a contradiction because there isn't that much room in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: A very quick way to say essentially the same idea:  Since $\mathbb R^2$ is second countable, not every point in the graph of $f$ can be isolated.

Comment: what about the case : $(x_n)_n$ to $c$ and $\frac{f(x_n)-f(c)}{x_n-c}$ converged ? @MonroeEskew

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309158/does-every-real-function-have-this-weak-derivation-property

Answer (score 55):

This has already been answered satisfactorily, but let me mention that it also follows from the much stronger (and noteworthy) fact that for every $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ there exists a dense $D\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that $f|_D$ is continuous [(Blumberg's theorem): see here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72800/every-real-function-has-a-dense-set-on-which-its-restriction-is-continuous) for references.  Given that this is true, take $c\in D$ and $x_n$ injective converging toward $c$ (which exists since $D$ is dense), and we have $f(x_n)$ converging to $f(c)$ by continuity of $f|_D$.

Comment: what about the case when $f(\mathbb R)=\mathbb N$, with $\forall n \in \mathbb N,f^{-1}(\{n\})$ is not dense in the real.

Comment: I can't think about a function continuous in D (dense in the real) with $f(D)=\mathbb N$, can you give an example.

Comment: @Dattier Blumberg's theorem is not that $f$ is continuous on $D$, it is that $f|_D$ is continuous.  The two are quite different.  (For some reason, every person who hears about Blumberg's theorem for the first time seems to fall for the same confusion.)

Comment: what the topologie on D ? (métrique no ?)

Comment: The topology on $D$ is the induced topology. (And as for an example of $f\colon D\to\mathbb{Z}$ surjective continuous, consider $f(x)=\lfloor x/\sqrt{2}\rfloor$ on $D=\mathbb{Q}$.)

Comment: The floor function is continuous on $\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb N$.

Comment: @Gro-Tsen: The function $x\mapsto \lfloor \sqrt 2x\rfloor$ defined on $\mathbb \Q$ is discontinuous at 0 for what it’s worth.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas Oh, yeah, right.  So remove $0$ from the domain or replace $\lfloor x/\sqrt{2}\rfloor$ by $\lfloor x-\sqrt{2}\rfloor$.

Answer (score 31):

It has "been known" since 1908 that for any such function, this holds for all but countably many real numbers $c$, even when we additionally require all the sequences to approach $c$ from the same side.

In May 1908 [William Henry Young](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Young.html) presented several results for general functions from $\mathbb R$ to ${\mathbb R},$ including a result implying that, given any such function, all but countably many real numbers $c$ have the property you're asking about. These results (for more about them, see [my answer here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/231360/a-search-for-theorems-which-appear-to-have-very-few-if-any-hypotheses/231462#231462)) may have been joint work with his wife, [Grace Chisholm Young](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/Biographies/Chisholm_Young.html), and the results were published in the 1908 paper cited below.

Young showed that for co-countably many real numbers $c$ we have

$$f(c) \in C^{-}(f,c) \;\; \text{and} \;\; f(c) \in C^{+}(f,c)$$

**Definition:** Given a function $f: {\mathbb R} \rightarrow {\mathbb R}$ and $c \in {\mathbb R}$, we let $C^{-}(f,c)$ be the set of all extended real numbers $y$ (i.e. $y$ can be $-\infty$ or $+\infty$) for which there exists a sequence $\left\{x_{k}\right\}$ such that for each $k$ we have $x_k < c,$ and we have $x_{k} \rightarrow c$ and $f(x_k) \rightarrow y.$ In other words, $C^{-}(f,c)$ is the set of all numbers (including $-\infty$ and $+\infty$) that can be obtained as a limit of $f$-values when using some sequence converging to $c$ from the left. The right version, $C^{+}(f,c),$ is defined analogously.

Incidentally, the requirement in this definition that each $x_k < c$ (and also each $x_k > c)$ allows you to find such sequences converging to $c$ that have infinitely many values.

William Henry Young, [*Sulle due funzioni a più valori costituite dai limiti d'una variabile reale a destra e a sinistra di ciascun punto*](https://books.google.com/books?id=nYsXAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA582) [On the two functions of multiple values that are determined by the left and right limits of a real variable at each point], **Atti della Accademia Reale dei Lincei. Rendiconti. Classe di Scienze fisiche, Matematiche e Naturali** (5) 17 #9 (1st semestre) (1908), 582-587. [Paper given at session dated 3 May 1908.]