# Does every real function have this weak derivation property?

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivations

After this question : [Does every real function have this weak continuity property?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/309019/does-every-real-function-have-this-weak-continuity-property)

Natrualy there are an other (more difficult) :

> Is it true that for every real function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, there exists a real sequence $(x_n)_n$, taking values different from $c$, converging to some real number $c$, such that the sequence $\left(\dfrac{f(c)-f(x_n)}{c-x_n}\right)_n$ converges  ?

Comment: See http://www.auburn.edu/~brownj4/tatras.pdf and for a higher dimensional generalization https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.1756.pdf

Comment: @Ashutosh: If I'm reading correctly, Theorem 6 in the Brown paper (which is attributed to Ceder) gives a positive answer to this question.  Perhaps you'd like to post as an answer?

Comment: What you're asking is whether an arbitrary function has, at some point in its domain, a finite [derived number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/262494/what-is-derived-number-definition-in-vitaly-covering). I initially thought the answer could be no for some functions, but the example I had in mind clearly (in retrospect) doesn't work. Perhaps the theorem @Ashutosh and Nate Eldredge mentioned answers the question. However, I don't have time to look now (in a rush to get out the door) --- for related ideas, google the phrases "derived number" and "sequential derivative".

Comment: Ceder's result allows infinite derivatives. We should use Brown's Corollary 1 to Theorem 9. I'll try to post more details later.

Comment: Here's another way to see this. By Denjoy-Young-Saks theorem, for any real function $f$, the set of points $x$ for which $\lim_{h \to 0^+} |f(x + h) - f(x)|/h = \infty$ has measure zero. It follows that for for a.e. $x$, there exists an injective sequence $x_n \downarrow x$ such that $(f(x_n) - f(x))/(x_n - x)$ converges.

Comment: @Ashutosh: I think you have enough for a decent answer. To give a bit more detail, the DYS theorem implication you mention follows from the fact that at any a.e. such point $x$ and for each $\delta>0,$ there exists a positive real number $M$ such that infinitely many of the difference quotients with $0<h<\delta$ lie within the compact set $[-M,M].$ Also, "almost all" cannot be strengthened in the sense of size, because given any measure zero set there exists a function (even a continuous and strictly increasing function) that has an infinite derivative at each point of that measure zero set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is yes : http://webhome.auburn.edu/~brownj4/tatras.pdf

PS : the answer was in the comments, but no one gave an answer